# Jquery infinite scroll with auto populated divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, infinite-scroll

I have some JavaScript that will auto populate a div from a JSON

```
const renderPosts = async (term) => {
let uri = 'http://localhost:3000/posts?_sort=likes&_order=desc';
if (term) {
    uri += `&q=${term}`;
}
const res = await fetch(uri);
const posts = await res.json();
let template = '';
posts.forEach(post => {
    template += `
        <div class="post">
            <a href="/html5up-future-imperfect/single.html?id=${ post.id }" class="image left"><img src="${post.image}" alt=""></a>
            <h1><a href="/html5up-future-imperfect/single.html?id=${ post.id }">${post.title}</a></h1>
            <p><small>${post.date}</small></p>
            <p>${post.body.slice(0, 200)}</p>
            <a href="/html5up-future-imperfect/single.html?id=${ post.id }">Read more...</a>
        </div>
    `
})
container.innerHTML = template;
```

}

However it loads all 50 at once. I am trying to figure out how to infinite scroll it to only load 5 at a time. I tried https://infinite-scroll.com/ but i can't seem to figure it out. this seems to only work if you have a static amount of objects that don't get populated when you first load the site.

Comment: The backend supplying the posts needs needs to paginate the data.  This is usually done by including an index and page size in the url.  And the documentation for [infinite-scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/) shows how to configure it to request the paginated data as needed using the [path option](https://infinite-scroll.com/options.html#path). Your existing code appears to send all the posts at once without any pagination.

Comment: Here is a [demo API](https://dummyjson.com/docs/posts) showing how pagination is used.  I don't think your question can be answered because you first need to fix the data pagination problem.

Comment: @Yogi thanks! I think I can use the dummyjson example to figure this out. Appreciate it